# jQuery/JavaScript find element that fired action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Any advice how to `console.log` the element that fired an hover action?
This is only for debugging a strange behavior I'm on on iOS.

I don't need to find the item on which action was performed, but who is performing the action.
For example on a simple mouse hover I want to `console.log` the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using native javascript, the `window.event` object is populated when an event fires, and the `event.srcElement` will give you DOM object that fired the event.

Using jQuery, the `this` reference inside an event handler will also give you the DOM object that handled the event.

Neither of these will tell you that `mouseover` was fired by a mouse, but they will give the DOM elements involved.

Answer (score 0):

Just check "originalEvent" if it is a mouseover:

```
$('div').mouseover(function(event){
   console.log(event.originalEvent);
});​
```

If you just have the event in your function, better check if it is a mouseover:

```
if(event.type=="mouseover"){
    console.log(event.originalEvent);
}
```

See the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6bP/2/).

Comment: i'm not sure i understand why you'd need to programatically discover that it's a mouseover event when the code is inside a mouseover handler

Comment: I just did that because of the question I don't know where he wants to log the mouseevent. Of course you don't need the mouseover check in my example but it was just to show the `event.originalEvent` access and to copy&paste it in the solution.
But you are right, it's confusing, I updated my answer.